# Xcode 6.0.1 Swift segmentation fault 11

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I'm having an issue with the final Xcode 6 release (6.0.1 to be more specific). I am no longer able to build my project I created on Xcode 6 beta 4, as the Swift compiler crashes on build for certain files (segmentation fault 11). Is there any way to fix this? One example of a file that can not be compiled would be this one:

```
import UIKit

class CategoryCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var Name : UILabel?
@IBOutlet var Thumbnail : UIImageView?
@IBOutlet var Description : UILabel?
var CategoryInfo: CategoryData! = nil

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

func loadCategoryInfo(category: CategoryData) {
    self.CategoryInfo = category
    self.Name!.text = category.Name
    self.Description!.text = category.Description
    self.Thumbnail!.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: FSTools.getDocumentSub("CategoryAssets/Thumbnails/" + category.ThumbnailName))
    self.Thumbnail!.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    self.Thumbnail!.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

}
```

I noticed that this question had already been asked about the Xcode 6 beta releases, but I find it kind of weird that this is still occurring on the final release of Xcode 6.

Comment: Which line / method causes the problem? Use "binary search" (commenting things out) to find out. The seg fault message may help you here as well (it sometimes specifies a line number).

Comment: Also, try the Xcode 6.1 beta. It fixes a number of these remaining seg fault issues.

Comment: And why are you using IBOutlet declarations with wrapped optionals? You know for a fact that the nib will load and set your outlets, so you should use explicitly unwrapped optionals, e.g. `@IBOutlet var Name : UILabel!`. This will save you from having to use all those exclamation marks later in your code.

Comment: And you don't need to write `var CategoryInfo: CategoryData! = nil`. You can delete the `nil` part. A declared optional is initialized to nil by default.

Comment: I get the same error with just released Xcode 6.3 in a file that used to build just fine and was't modified since `let (_, summary) = matchController.addPointforTeamAtPosition(command == extensionCommandTeam1Point ? 0 : 1)`.